# Browers Logs Clear on Repeat calls to browser.driver.manage.logs.get(:browser)

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir

If I pull the logs in my Selenium/Watir projects using `browser.driver.manage.logs.get(:browser)` I notice that it clears the logs so that repeats calls do not produce the same results.

Is there way to just POLL the logs so you can make repeated calls and get the same results? (Using Chrome)

Comment: You want an aggregated log?  Quick/dirty way: write to a file in append mode (after each get).

Comment: I want to use the log like an array, but I'd rather not store its state somewhere. I have to check the log at different places in different classes. I guess I could create a static var (or use your way) but I was hoping there was just a way to poll `browser.driver.manage.logs.get(:browser)` (get without clearing)

Comment: I believe managing logs is different per browser. Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Chrome browser